# My docker commnds fails on wget when I make the image

Tags: node.js, docker

I am trying to make a docker image by nodejs, the Dockerfile is as follow:

```
FROM node:9-slim
RUN mkdir -p /python2 && chown -R root:root /python2
WORKDIR /python2
RUN wget https://www.python.org/ftp/python/2.7.18/Python-2.7.18.tgz
RUN tar -xvf Python-2.7.18.tgz
USER root
RUN export PATH=$PATH:/python2
RUN mkdir -p /var/tmp/thermo && chown -R root:root /var/tmp/thermo
WORKDIR /var/tmp/thermo
COPY * ./
RUN npm install
EXPOSE 3000
CMD [ "npm", "run" ]
```

whenever, I run

```
docker build -t thermo-api .
```

it fails on wget line:

```
Step 4/13 : RUN wget https://www.python.org/ftp/python/2.7.18/Python-2.7.18.tgz
 ---> Running in c462b48d159b
INFO[2020-07-29T05:08:53.838143536Z] shim containerd-shim started                  address="/containerd-shim/moby/c462b48d159b0990f768c94a499072df46cc2933b6d4e0d1e49e7e83dd480b91/shim.sock" debug=false pid=6864
converted 'https://www.python.org/ftp/python/2.7.18/Python-2.7.18.tgz' (ANSI_X3.4-1968) -> 'https://www.python.org/ftp/python/2.7.18/Python-2.7.18.tgz' (UTF-8)
--2020-07-29 05:08:54--  https://www.python.org/ftp/python/2.7.18/Python-2.7.18.tgz
Resolving www.python.org (www.python.org)... failed: Name or service not known.
wget: unable to resolve host address 'www.python.org'
```

I am not sure whats wrong with my commands?

Comment: Please give a few more details: which OS do you run, what is your Docker setup? From the error message it seems you cannot reach DNS from within the container.

Comment: The VM which I am running docker on is Linux. I can run the exact wget command on the VM but not within docker commands.

Comment: Seems to me that wget cant resolve python.org. I would guess its network problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since it's working on your local machine (or VM), maybe you're experiencing some network issues? Is there a proxy your docker should be aware of?

Maybe try building with `network=host`:

```
docker build --network=host -t thermo-api .
```

And if you're within a company firewall you should include `--http_proxy` and `--https_proxy` variables to your build command.